# Using raster cell area in a calculation using Python

Tags: python, raster, area

I have a large raster full of integer values (1-20) and want to calculate the total area of cells of each value using Python. The raster spans a wide range of latitudes and so the area of each cell is quite different.

I would normally do this in R, looping through each value, filtering and binarising the raster to represent that value only and then multiplying by cell area, but this file is too large and R is too slow. Is there a Python command that is the equivalent of cellSize (terra for R) or Area (raster for R)? Or is there a more efficient way to do this?

I am relatively new to Python.

Answer (score 1):

Cast your raster to a numpy array and use unique to get a list of all the different values and a list of the count of those values.  [See the example here](https://www.statology.org/numpy-count-unique/).